# Amplify and convert negative pulse to positive pulse

Tags: operational-amplifier, pulse, inverting-amplifier

I am looking for design recommendation. Attachment is the block diagram of the system. We have a single photon detector (SPD) (https://www.idquantique.com/quantum-sensing/products/id281/) outputting -0.1V, > 5ns pulse of burst rate up to 10 MHz. We need to count these pulses using a photon counter. Our photon counter takes CMOS input pulses only. I need to convert this negative -0.1V to CMOS signal. 
I need to make sure the amplifier will not affect significantly the timing jitter of the output from the SPD which is 20ps. I want to maintain this number as close to 20ps as possible.

I chose this op amp https://www.analog.com/en/products/ad8009.html#product-overview
This is 5.5V/ns slew rate, 545 ps rising time, and 10ns settling time. 
Please advice me on this selection.

[image]

Comment: Can you explain, why the jitter is so important if you just count the pulses?

Comment: What I don't understand is why you can't contact the folks making the [ID281](https://www.idquantique.com/quantum-sensing/products/id281/) and just ask them. Cripes, I'm sure they will support you very well. That thing is not cheap and I'm sure they want you to be successful using their products. Customers of products I've worked on are well supported by technical sales staff -- usually including at least one Ph.D. in physics who can handle detailed questions like this. I'm sure this company has similiar support capabilities. You should just ask.

Comment: @jonk thank you. Yes, they recommended this https://www.minicircuits.com/pdfs/ZFL-2000GH+.pdf
Which amplified the signal to CMOS level but negative voltage. My photon counter can only takes positive signal. I believe I just need an inverter to make it work so I did not ask for further support

Comment: @MarkoBuršič Yes. This photon counter will count and also record the arrival time of the signal compare to a reference clock. Therefore I need the arrival time to be accurate within a certain range. Right now it is 20ps jitter. I hope to stay within 30ps after the amplifier

Comment: @Lac You should look for a "coax broadband pulse inverter" that is sufficient for your application. Something like [this](https://www.markimicrowave.com/Assets/datasheets/INV-0065.pdf). You might contact the company making your amplifier to see if they also have one of those, or if they have a suggestion for you.

Comment: @jonk Out of curiosity, if he did want to do this with an opamp (probably after relaxing his constraints a bit), do you know what parameter of an opamp would determine the jitter?

Comment: @BeB00 I think any "jitter" spec can only be given by understanding how an analog signal is converted to digital and would require details on the OP's CMOS inputs. I don't think that's a stand-alone specification for an opamp itself, without knowing what is doing the "jittering." ;)

Comment: _"< 5ns pulse"_ - What is the _minimum_ pulse width you need to detect?

Comment: @BruceAbbott Sorry. My big mistake. I meant "greater than" 5ns. The min pulse width I need is 5ns